# Trouble understanding an insert node function from Deitel&Deitel's book

Tags: c, list

I'm studying this function from Deitel&Deitel's C manual, but it isn't much documentated (at least, not enough for me to understand) and I'm having a hard time getting it.

```
void insert(ListNodePtr *sPtr, char value){
  ListNodePtr newPtr = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));

  if(newPtr != NULL){
    newPtr->data = value;
    newPtr->nextPtr = NULL;

    ListNodePtr previousPtr = NULL;
    ListNodePtr currentPtr = *sPtr;

    while(currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data){ 
      previousPtr = currentPtr;                            
      currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr; 
    }

    if(previousPtr == NULL){
      newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
      *sPtr = newPtr;
    }
    else{ 
      previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr; //*
      newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr; 
    }
  }
  else{
    printf("%c not inserted. No memory available.\n", value);
  }
}
```

1. Why is there a need for previousPtr and currentPtr to exist? Can't I just move through the nodes without those variables?
2. isn't previousPtr->nextPtr (*) just currentPtr? Why does this function not work when attaching newPtr to currentPtr?
3. Am I right in assuming that previousPtr and currentPtr aren't actually contiguous but are called like they are for simplicity?

Note that this function puts elements in an ordered way.

Comment: Linus Torvalds would **not** consider the author of this code as having [**good taste**](https://medium.com/@bartobri/applying-the-linus-tarvolds-good-taste-coding-requirement-99749f37684a)

Comment: Nor would he have felt the author understood pointers very well [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/)

Comment: If the 'head' pointer contained NULL,  I.E. list was empty, Then this code will not work for inserting the very first node (it needs the address of 'head', not the contents of 'head'

Comment: Another HUGE point of confusion you are likely having will be resolved from your review of [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers). (answer: No)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to the world of coding in C! The logic here deals with working around the `NULL` pointer, a concept that can be a little tricky to grasp. In a sense, `NULL` means there's "nothing" at the pointer address. Before we get started, here's a [few](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/linked-list/singly-linked-list/tutorial/) [good](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-2-inserting-a-node/) [tutorials](https://www.learn-c.org/en/Linked_lists) on singly-linked lists, which you might be interested in reviewing.

---

> Why is there a need for previousPtr and currentPtr to exist? Can't I just move through the nodes without those variables?

The code you're seeing is a [linked list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/linked-list/). Without seeing the `struct` definition for it, it's hard to say more, but the gist of a linked list is that data is stored in the heap, and is accessed through pointers. When you insert into a linked list, you first have to find the spot you want to insert into.

```c
    //this code traverses the linked list. each node has a nextPtr value, which 
    //points, predictably, to the next value. if this is the end of the list,
    //the nextPtr value will be NULL.

    //first, check if the current pointer is NULL. this happens in two cases:
    // - the list is totally empty, in which case this is the first pointer.
    // - the end of the list has been reached.
    //second, if it's not NULL, check the value. 
    //if the value is greater than the current pointer, we'll insert the new data here.
    while(currentPtr != NULL && value > currentPtr->data){

      //entering this loop means we've encountered a non-null next ptr, as well as one
      //whose value is larger than this one. we'll go to the next node.

      //save the node we're at now
      previousPtr = currentPtr;   
      //go to the next node                         
      currentPtr = currentPtr->nextPtr; 
    }
```

We're on our way now - after this loop exits, we've either reached the end of the list, or a point where we want to insert the value. First, though, a sanity check - does the list even have any nodes yet?

```c
    //check to see whether there's even a list yet. note that previousPtr starts at
    //NULL - if this doesn't change, the while loop didn't traverse anything, and 
    //the sPtr (start pointer) was NULL.

    if(previousPtr == NULL){
      //start pointer was NULL - make a new list head

      //assign newPtr->nextPtr to NULL
      newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;

      //assign sPtr to the new node we've made
      *sPtr = newPtr;
    }
```

Here's where we get to why we need `previousPtr` and `currentPtr`.

```c
    //we've either reached the end of the list, OR we've reached a value 
    //we want to insert to.
    //
    //if we've reached the end of the list, currentPtr is NULL, and we can't access
    //its value or its nextPtr. if we hadn't kept previousPtr, we'd know we were at
    //the end of the list, but would have no way to back up one pointer in order to 
    //add the new node.
    //
    //even if we haven't reached the end of the list, currentPtr doesn't know what 
    //the previous pointer was, so we'd have no way to insert something where currentPtr 
    //used to be.

    else{ 

      //make previousPtr point to the new pointer
      previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr; //*
      //make the newPtr point to currentPtr. note that it's irrelevant if this
      //is the end of the list or not - currentPtr will be NULL if it is, and if it 
      //isn't, the list will still point to whatever was in currentPtr - just with
      //newPtr coming first.
      newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr; 
    }
```

So - `currentPtr` and `previousPtr` are required because, in order to insert into the list, you need a way to track which new node you'll be adding the data to. You can move through the nodes without those values, and some functions indeed *don't* use those variables - common examples are `find(int value)` or similar. If you want to do `insert` without them, you can, but it's a bit more tricky, because you have to reference `currentPtr->nextPtr->value` - and if `nextPtr` is `NULL`, your code will crash.

---

> isn't previousPtr->nextPtr (*) just currentPtr? Why does this function not work when attaching newPtr to currentPtr?

You're correct, `previousPtr->nextPtr` is indeed `currentPtr` - however, there's no guarantee `currentPtr` isn't `NULL`. You run the risk of a segfault if you attach to `currentPtr`. Additionally, if it isn't `NULL`, that means the data won't be attached properly if you try to bind to it. For example:

```
currentPtr has a new value:
                                newPtr(5)
ptr(9) -> ptr(7) -> previousPtr(6) -> currentPtr(4) -> ptr(3) -> ptr(1) -> NULL


attach to previousPtr (correct)
                                    newPtr(5) -v
ptr(9) -> ptr(7) -> previousPtr(6) -^          currentPtr(4) -> ptr(3) -> ptr(1) -> NULL


attach to currentPtr (out of order, and currentPtr might be NULL)
                                                     newPtr(5) -v
ptr(9) -> ptr(7) -> previousPtr(6) -> currentPtr(4) -^          ptr(3) -> ptr(1) -> NULL



currentPtr is NULL:
                      newPtr(4)
ptr(6) -> previousPtr(5) -> NULL [currentPtr]


attach to previousPtr (correct)
                          newPtr(4) -v
ptr(6) -> previousPtr(5) -^          NULL

attach to currentPtr (SEGFAULT)
                                  newPtr(4)
ptr(6) -> previousPtr(5) -> NULL -^ 

                            ^^^^^^^  can't do this - NULL doesn't have a nextPtr!
```

---

> Am I right in assuming that previousPtr and currentPtr aren't actually contiguous but are called like they are for simplicity?

Correct again! `previousPtr` and `currentPtr` are not contiguous in memory - they're created on the heap, which [is not contiguous.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/) The variables are so named for programmer's ease-of-use.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

1.You can move through the nodes without using the previousPtr, but in the next section you have to decide whether you came to the end of the list or not. That is where the previousPtr helpfull:

```
   if(previousPtr == NULL){     #end of the List
     newPtr->nextPtr = *sPtr;
     *sPtr = newPtr;
   }
   else{    #some place within the List
     previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr;
     newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr; 
   }
```

2. You right, it is currentPtr and in this case the idea is that we want to push a node between two connected nodes:

```
   else{ 
     previousPtr->nextPtr = newPtr; //*
     newPtr->nextPtr = currentPtr; 
   }
```

You set the previous node to point on your new node and your new node to the next node, which in turn is pointed as currentPtr.

3. They are not contiguous in the case explained in 2. This is the case when you want to insert a node in the middle of the List. This happens because you want to keep the List ordered.

Comment: Wait, previousPtr checks whether the list reached its end...? I thought that condition returned true at the beginning, since previousPtr would've been equal to currentPtr which is NULL. Is this wrong?

Comment: Of note is that there's never any guarantee `previousPtr` and `currentPtr` are contiguous, regardless of the case. Heap memory is allocated in [random order.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stack-vs-heap-memory-allocation/)